# Does PL/SQL have an equivalent StringTokenizer to Java's?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, tokenize, stringtokenizer

I use java.util.StringTokenizer for simple parsing of delimited strings in java.  I have a need for the same type of mechanism in pl/sql.  I could write it, but if it already exists, I would prefer to use that.  Anyone know of a pl/sql implementation?  Some useful alternative?

Answer (score 4):

PL/SQL does include a basic one for comma separated lists (`DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE`).

Example:

```
DECLARE
   lv_tab_length   BINARY_INTEGER;
   lt_array   DBMS_UTILITY.lname_array;
BEGIN
   DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE( list => 'one,two,three,four'
                              , tablen => lv_tab_length
                              , tab => lt_array
                              );

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'lv_tab_length = ['||lv_tab_length||']' );

   FOR i IN 1..lv_tab_length
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '['||lt_array( i )||']' );
   END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Or see this Ask Tom link for other ideas...

[Ak Tom - "varying elements in IN list"](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:110612348061)

Comment: This feature comes with a real snag: DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE only recognises tokens which could legitimately be Oracle object names.  So it's usefulness is somewhat constrained.

Answer (score 3):

if you have APEX installed, the function [`APEX_UTIL.string_to_table`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_util.htm#CHDFEEJD) does just that.

Comment: If you have 11g APEX is installed as standard, so you will have access to this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

PL/SQL does not come with a built-in tokenizer.  However, it is relatively simple to build out of SQL or PL/SQL.  Adrian Billington's web site [has several solutions](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=412).  In addition, if you are on 10g, you could use [this code from Tanel Poder](http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2007/06/20/my-version-of-sql-string-to-table-tokenizer/), which does it in SQL using regex.

Admittedly it would be easier if Oracle just included the dang facility as one of their built-ins.

Comment: Are you kidding? How long did it take them to add Boolean support? And you *still* can't store a Boolean in a table. >=(

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to write a Java stored proc (there is a JVM inside the database), that means you can use java.util.StringTokenizer. You have to wrap a Java stored proc inside a PL/SQL procedure/function.

Se here for an example: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=2575374&#2575374

Sadly I doný understand Java's checked exceptions so the exception handling isn't really great (I'm not a Java dev).