# passing semicolon separated data to function

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, mybatis, stringtokenizer

I wanted to modify the below procedure to send data in the form 1;2;3 .In the below procedure I am sending data like 1 then I check if the data is a valid number if yes then I get query to some table and get the data count. I am not able to modify the procedure to send semicolon separated data and check if the data is a number or not ,here p_in_field_value should be like 1;2;3 which should be passed to below function.

```
FUNCTION p_get_option_value(p_in_field_value IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    v_is_number boolean;
    v_count number;
    v_option_val VARCHAR2(300);
   begin
     v_is_number := pkg_trial.f_check_value_numeric(p_in_field_value);
       IF (v_is_number = TRUE) THEN
                                  select count(id) into v_count from t_field_option where field_option_id=p_in_field_value;
          if(v_count >=1) THEN
          v_option_val:=  pkg_form_common.f_option_values(p_in_field_value);
          return v_option_val;  
          else
            return p_in_field_value;
                    END IF;

      ELSE
       return p_in_field_value;
       END IF; 

FUNCTION f_check_value_numeric(p_in_field_value IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    v_is_number number;
   begin
     v_is_number := to_number(p_in_field_value);
      return TRUE;
    exception
       when others then
       return FALSE;

   END f_check_value_numeric;
```

Please let me know how to perform this ?

Comment: Could you please review your description for typos,  and add in some detail about what you want returned from the function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does PL/SQL have an equivalent StringTokenizer to Java's?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520733/does-pl-sql-have-an-equivalent-stringtokenizer-to-javas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure how the value of v_option_val should be calculated, but you can split the semicolon seperated data as follows:

```
FUNCTION p_get_option_value(p_in_field_value IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    v_is_number boolean;
    v_count number;
    v_option_val VARCHAR2(300);
    v_pos     NUMBER;
    v_in_field_valid  VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_val     VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    v_in_field_valid  := p_in_field_value;

    WHILE v_in_field_valid IS NOT NULL 
    LOOP 

      v_pos :=  instr(v_in_field_valid, ';');
      IF v_pos  = 0 THEN
        v_val := v_in_field_valid;
        v_insurance_value := NULL;
      ELSE 
        v_val := SUBSTR(v_in_field_valid, 1, v_pos -1);
        v_in_field_valid := substr(v_str, v_pos + 1);
      END IF;

      v_is_number := pkg_trial.f_check_value_numeric(v_val);
       IF (v_is_number = TRUE) THEN
                                  select count(id) into v_count from t_field_option where field_option_id=v_val;
          if(v_count >=1) THEN
          v_option_val:=  v_option_val || pkg_form_common.f_option_values(v_val);
     END LOOP
    return p_in_field_value;
   END;
```