# How to skip comma from csv using double quotes

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, plsql

I am getting a string in the below format after reading data from a csv file

`v_lastline = '29218368,8062115," Benedict Canyon Equities, Inc",CLS,,FAX';`

I just want to convert it into an array while will contain 6 values, the comma before the `, Inc` needs to be escaped.
Can any one please suggest whats the best way to do it in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14614065/266304), but you have empty elements in your list; and a simple translation of one of the patterns I tried there skips those:

```
var v_lastline varchar2(50);
exec :v_lastline := '29218368,8062115," Benedict Canyon Equities, Inc",CLS,,FAX';

select level as lvl,
  regexp_substr(:v_lastline, '("[^"]*"|[^,]+)', 1, level) as element
from dual
connect by level <= regexp_count(:v_lastline, '("[^"]*"|[^,]+)');

       LVL ELEMENT                                
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1 29218368                                
         2 8062115                                 
         3 " Benedict Canyon Equities, Inc"        
         4 CLS                                     
         5 FAX
```

If you can identify a special character that will never appear in the data then you can work around that by putting that into the empty elements by changing every comma to comma+character, and then removing it after the split:

```
select level as lvl,
  replace(regexp_substr(replace(:v_lastline, ',', ',§'),
    '(§"[^"]*"|[^,]+)', 1, level), '§', null) as element
from dual
connect by regexp_substr(replace(:v_lastline, ',', ',§'),
  '(§"[^"]*"|[^,]+)', 1, level) is not null;

       LVL ELEMENT                                
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1 29218368                                
         2 8062115                                 
         3 " Benedict Canyon Equities, Inc"        
         4 CLS                                     
         5                                         
         6 FAX
```

It's an extension of a common method to split delimited strings, [which is explained in detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19195465/266304).

- `replace(:v_lastline, ',', ',§')` changes `...,CLS,,FAX` to `...,§CLS,§,§FAX`, where `§` is a character you'll never see.
- `regexp_substr(..., '(§"[^"]*"|[^,]+)', 1, level)` tokenises the updated value with a regex that looks for any double-quote-enclosed value (now preceded by the special character too) **or** a non-comma; the order of the evaluation means commas inside the quoted part are ignored.
- the `level` is part of the hierarchical query syntax, where:
- `connect by regexp_substr(<same value and pattern>) is not null` just figured out how many tokens there are.
- and finally `replace(regexp_substr(...), , '§', null)` removes the special character used in the first step.

You can then remove the double-quotes too with a further level of `replace()`, and trim whitespace, if you want/need to.

You have't said quite what you mean by an array, but you can run that query in PL/SQL and bulk-collect into a collection if that's what you intend to work with. For example, using the built-in ODCIVARCHAR2LIST collection type:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  v_lastline varchar2(50);
  v_array sys.odcivarchar2list;
begin
  v_lastline := '29218368,8062115," Benedict Canyon Equities, Inc",CLS,,FAX';

  select trim(replace(replace(
    regexp_substr(replace(:v_lastline, ',', ',§'),
      '(§"[^"]*"|[^,]+)', 1, level), '§', null), '"', null))
  bulk collect into v_array
  from dual
  connect by regexp_substr(replace(:v_lastline, ',', ',§'),
    '(§"[^"]*"|[^,]+)', 1, level) is not null;

  dbms_output.put_line('Number of elements: ' || v_array.count);
  for i in 1..v_array.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Index ' || i || ' has: ' || v_array(i));
  end loop;
end;
/

Number of elements: 6
Index 1 has: 29218368
Index 2 has: 8062115
Index 3 has: Benedict Canyon Equities, Inc
Index 4 has: CLS
Index 5 has: 
Index 6 has: FAX
```

---

With multiple empty elements this also (now) works:

```
exec :v_lastline := '29218368,8062115," Benedict Canyon Equities, Inc",,,,,,,CLS,,,,,FAX,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,INVOICE';
select level as lvl,
  replace(regexp_substr(replace(:v_lastline, ',', ',§'),
    '(§"[^"]*"|[^,]+)', 1, level), '§', null) as element
from dual
connect by regexp_substr(replace(:v_lastline, ',', ',§'),
  '(§"[^"]*"|[^,]+)', 1, level) is not null;

       LVL ELEMENT                                
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1 29218368                                
         2 8062115                                 
         3 " Benedict Canyon Equities, Inc"        
         4                                         
...
         9                                         
        10 CLS                                     
        11                                         
...
        14                                         
        15 FAX                                     
        16                                         
...
        32                                         
        33 INVOICE
```

Comment: Its failing for this strings like `'29218368,8062115," Benedict Canyon Equities, Inc",,,` , instead of returning 6 values its returning 4 values.

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy - updated with a slightly more complicated pattern, with all comma changed to comma+character.

Comment: Great Alex, now it seems to working fine, Let me fine if my csv contains any other wired patterns.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you. Possibly saved me couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of your CSV if fixed, you can try with something like this:

```
with text(text) as ( select '29218368,8062115," Benedict Canyon Equities, Inc",CLS,,FAX' from dual)
select level,
       trim(',' from 
                       case
                        when level in (1,2) then
                            regexp_substr(text, '(.*??)\,', 1, level)
                        when level = 3 then
                            regexp_substr(text, '"(.*??)"', 1, 1)
                        when level in (4,5) then
                            regexp_substr(text, '(.*??)\,', instr(text, '"', 1, 2), level -2) 
                        when level = 6 then       
                            regexp_substr(text, '\,([^\,]*)', instr(text, '"', 1, 2), 3)
                       end
            )
from text
connect by level <= 6
```

This makes strong assumptions on the structure of CSV, by treating each part in a different way, but it seems to me difficult to find a really generic solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without regular expressions, first of all create two helper functions

```
/* CAR   select car('hello,world,bla') from dual --> hello */
create or replace function car(PI_STR in varchar2,
                               PI_SEPARATOR in varchar2 default ',')
  return varchar2 is l_pos number;
begin
  l_pos := instr(PI_STR, PI_SEPARATOR);

  if l_pos > 0 then
    return substr(PI_STR, 1, l_pos - 1);
  end if;

  return PI_STR;
end;

/* CDR select cdr('hello,world,bla') from dual --> world,bla */
create or replace function cdr(PI_STR in varchar2,
                               PI_SEPARATOR in varchar2 default ',')
  return varchar2 is l_pos number;
begin
  l_pos := instr(PI_STR, PI_SEPARATOR);

  if l_pos > 0 then
    return substr(PI_STR, l_pos + length(PI_SEPARATOR));
  end if;

  return '';
end;
```

now: extract by ',' and for each result concat with next entry if escape character is found upto next escape character:

```
create or replace type csv_col is table of varchar2(4000);

create or replace function get_columns(PI_STR in varchar2,
                                       PI_SEPARATOR in varchar2,
                                       PI_ESC_CHAR in varchar2)
  return csv_col pipelined is l_car varchar2(4000);
l_cdr varchar2(4000);
l_car_esc varchar2(4000);
begin
  l_car := car(PI_STR, PI_SEPARATOR);
  l_cdr := cdr(PI_STR, PI_SEPARATOR);
  -- check for escape char
  l_car_esc := cdr(l_car, PI_ESC_CHAR);
  if l_car_esc is not null then
    l_car := l_car_esc || PI_SEPARATOR || car(l_cdr, PI_ESC_CHAR);
    l_cdr := cdr(cdr(l_cdr, PI_ESC_CHAR), PI_SEPARATOR);
  end if;
  loop
    if l_car is null and l_cdr is null then
      exit;
    end if;

    pipe row(l_car);
    l_car     := car(l_cdr, PI_SEPARATOR);
    l_cdr     := cdr(l_cdr, PI_SEPARATOR);
    l_car_esc := cdr(l_car, PI_ESC_CHAR);
    if l_car_esc is not null then
      l_car := l_car_esc || PI_SEPARATOR || car(l_cdr, PI_ESC_CHAR);
      l_cdr := cdr(cdr(l_cdr, PI_ESC_CHAR), PI_SEPARATOR);
      dbms_output.put_line(l_car);
      dbms_output.put_line(l_cdr);
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

call it like this:

```
select *
  from table(get_columns('29218368,8062115," Benedict Canyon Equities, Inc",CLS,,FAX',
                         ',',
                         '"'));
```

--> result

```
29218368
8062115
 Benedict Canyon Equities, Inc
CLS

FAX
```