# oracle split by comma a quoted string

Tags: oracle11g, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

I have found tons of questions like this, but none of them are 100% suitable for me. i have oracle 11g express

I have that string

```
'abcd,123,,defoifcd,"comma, in string",87765,,,hello'
```

it means normally a comma separates the data, but could be empty data (even more in a series), and if there is comma in the data it is quoted.

so far the best reg exp is that one

```
'("[^"]*"|[^,]+)'
```

but this puts at the end of all of the empty data using that query

```
with test as 
(select 
'abcd,123,,defoifcd,"comma, in string", 87765,,,hello'
str from dual  
)  
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '("[^"]*"|[^,]+)', 1, rownum) split
from test  
connect by level <= length (regexp_replace (str, '("[^"]*"|[^,]+)'))  + 1;
```

i also tried replacing the empty data with ,n/a, so to have

```
'abcd,123,n/a,defoifcd,"comma, in string",87765,n/a,n/a,hello'
```

but regexp_replace replaces only the first occurence of the empty data

```
select 
regexp_replace('abcd,123,,defoifcd,"comma, in string",87765,,,hello', '(,,)', ',n/a,')
str from dual;
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35502233/266304) one you looked at already? That's using replace rather than regexp_replace to put a dummy value in...

Comment: yep, that kind of replace indeed a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work and handles NULLs:

```
SQL> with test as
    (select
    'abcd,123,,defoifcd,"comma, in string", 87765,,,hello'
    str from dual
    )
    select trim('"' from REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '(".*?"|.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, NULL, 1)) split
    from test
    connect by level<=length(regexp_replace(str,'".*?"|[^,]*'))+1;

SPLIT
----------------------------------------------------
abcd
123

defoifcd
comma, in string
 87765


hello

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

This post provided the impetus for the solution: https://community.oracle.com/thread/528107?tstart=0