# Split comma separated values with line gaps and nulls into columns in table via pl/sql procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, regexp-substr

I have a string, clob value in table which i need to split into columns .
Source table query:

```
Insert into disp_data(id,data) values(100,
'"Project title as per the outstanding Requirements","The values are not with respect to the requirement and analysis done by the team. 
Also it is difficult to prepare a scenario notwithstanding the fact it is difficult. This user story is going to be slightly complex however it is up to the team","Active","Disabled","25 tonnes of fuel","www.examplesites.com/html.asp&net;","","","","","25"');
```

In the clob column value there are spaces, null value and line gaps also.
So when i try splitting it using

```
select regexp_substr(data,'[^,]+',1,level) from disp_data 
connect by regexp_substr(data,'[^,]+',1,level) is not null.
```

Problem is for the large text with line gaps, it is splitting it into different rows. I had thought of using the above result set and pivot but am unable to.

I need to get this data as columns and push in the destination table-push_data_temp.

```
select pid,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11 from push_data_temp;
```

The clob column has 11 comma separated values that need to be pushed into this table as columns.
This entire process needs to be done via pl/sql procedure.

The result in push_data_temp should look like this.
[image]

ANy help would be much appreciated.
DB is oracle 19c

Comment: Are you only stuck with pivot and the splitting of data into rows are fine?

Comment: No, splitting is also not correct

Comment: Understood and if I am not wrong the answers already gave you the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regular expression [needs to allow for nulls](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5b012f759bbc38cad917c318c8e227a3), i.e. consecutive commas (but hopefully you don't have commas within any of the quoted strings...). If you have multiple source rows then it's easier to split with a recursive CTE:

```
with rcte (id, data, lvl, result) as (
  select id, data, 1, regexp_substr(data, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 1, null, 1)
  from disp_data
  union all
  select id, data, lvl + 1, regexp_substr(data, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1)
  from rcte
  where lvl <= regexp_count(data, ',')
)
select id, lvl, result
from rcte
order by id, lvl;
```

You can then pivot the result into the columns you want:

```
with rcte (id, data, lvl, result) as (
  select id, data, 1, regexp_substr(data, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 1, null, 1)
  from disp_data
  union all
  select id, data, lvl + 1, regexp_substr(data, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1)
  from rcte
  where lvl <= regexp_count(data, ',')
)
select *
from (
  select id, lvl, result
  from rcte
)
pivot (max(result) as col for (lvl) in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=040c01f95a6125780c1843e46ecfed42)

And you can use that directly in an insert statement:

```
insert into push_data_temp (pid,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11)
with rcte (id, data, lvl, result) as (
  select id, data, 1, regexp_substr(data, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 1, null, 1)
  from disp_data
  union all
  select id, data, lvl + 1, regexp_substr(data, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1)
  from rcte
  where lvl <= regexp_count(data, ',')
)
select *
from (
  select id, lvl, result
  from rcte
)
pivot (max(result) as col for (lvl) in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=22bc83c2235411979f765317ae9f7ded)

No PL/SQL needed, but you can still wrap it in a procedure if you want to.

---

> I have to take as clob and it is throwing error as inconsistent datatype

You need to cast the tokens as `varchar2`, which limits their length (either 4k or 32k depending on Oracle version and settings):

```
with rcte (id, data, lvl, result) as (
  select id, data, 1,
    cast(regexp_substr(data, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 1, null, 1) as varchar2(4000))
  from disp_data
  union all
  select id, data, lvl + 1,
    cast(regexp_substr(data, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1) as varchar2(4000))
  from rcte
  where lvl <= regexp_count(data, ',')
)
...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=94e08c778a3834f28384dd7e07edddf2) with CLOB (and connect-by examples removed, as they break it...)

---

> when i try for text with commas in between, it splits data unevenly.

That's why I said "hopefully you don't have commas within any of the quoted strings". As you don't have any really empty elements - you have `...","","...` rather than `...,,...` - you can skip the concern about those I suppose, and use a different pattern:

```
with rcte (id, data, lvl, result) as (
  select id, data, 1,
    cast(regexp_substr(data, '("[^"]*"|[^,]+)', 1, 1, null, 1) as varchar2(4000))
  from disp_data
  union all
  select id, data, lvl + 1,
    cast(regexp_substr(data, '("[^"]*"|[^,]+)', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1) as varchar2(4000))
  from rcte
  where lvl <= regexp_count(data, '("[^"]*"|[^,]+)')
)
...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=121bcb913055eb470644bfca7bcbda80)

If you did have to deal with null elements then it's still possible, [but more work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35502233/266304). This also won't deal with escaped double-quotes without strings. At some point it will be easier to write your own parser in PL/SQL; or even to write the data to disk and read it back in as an external table which can handle all of this for you.

Comment: @Vini - I used varchar2 because db<>fiddle broke with CLOB... you just need to cast the elements first. Added that to my answer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks.. there is one small doubt if you have time for it.. I need to do this for larger text. However when i try for text with commas in between, it splits data unevenly. I have edited the data in sql fiddle. Can you take a look? For col2 tet, i add 2 commas in the text. The result you see on right, is splitting data incorrectly probably due to commas. can this be handled? The text i have changed for second column is, added column after :. The values are and Also it is difficult to. I need to amend query so that the commas are included inside text

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=140f1978cc1fff9d5e3b14d3a107d7eb

Comment: @Vini - that's why I said "hopefully you don't have commas within any of the quoted strings", as you didn't in the sample in the question. Updated with a version that works with the new example.

Comment: I know, they added to requirement at last moment. Nevertheless thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

Enter [Polymorphic Table Functions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/polymorphic-table-functions-18c)!

You can use these to dynamically convert [comma-separated strings into a list of columns](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_F99JG73Z169WENDTTQFDQ0J09.html):

```
create table disp_data (
  id int, data varchar2(1000)
);
Insert into disp_data(id,data) values(100,
'"Project title as per the outstanding Requirements","The values are not with respect to the requirement and analysis done by the team. 
Also it is difficult to prepare a scenario notwithstanding the fact it is difficult. This user story is going to be slightly complex however it is up to the team","Active","Disabled","25 tonnes of fuel","www.examplesites.com/html.asp&net;","","","","","25"');
commit;

create or replace package csv_pkg as  
  /* The describe function defines the new columns */  
  function describe (  
    tab in out dbms_tf.table_t,  
    col_names varchar2  
  ) return dbms_tf.describe_t;  
  
  /* Fetch_rows sets the values for the new columns */  
  procedure fetch_rows (col_names varchar2);  
end csv_pkg;  
/

create or replace package body csv_pkg as  
  function describe(  
    tab in out dbms_tf.table_t,  
    col_names varchar2  
  )   
    return dbms_tf.describe_t as  
    new_cols dbms_tf.columns_new_t;  
    col_id   pls_integer := 2;  
  begin   
    
    /* Enable the source colun for reading */  
    tab.column(1).pass_through := FALSE;  
    tab.column(1).for_read     := TRUE;  
    new_cols(1) := tab.column(1).description;  
      
    /* Extract the column names from the header string,  
       creating a new column for each   
     */  
    for j in 1 .. ( length(col_names) - length(replace(col_names,',')) ) + 1 loop   
      new_cols(col_id) := dbms_tf.column_metadata_t(  
        name=>regexp_substr(col_names, '[^,]+', 1, j),--'c'||j,   
        type=>dbms_tf.type_varchar2  
      );  
      col_id := col_id + 1;  
    end loop;  
    
    return dbms_tf.describe_t( new_columns => new_cols );  
  end;  
  
  procedure fetch_rows (col_names varchar2) as   
    rowset    dbms_tf.row_set_t;  
    row_count pls_integer;  
  begin  
    /* read the input data set */  
    dbms_tf.get_row_set(rowset, row_count => row_count);  
      
    /* Loop through the input rows... */  
    for i in 1 .. row_count loop  
      /* ...and the defined columns, extracting the relevant value   
         start from 2 to skip the input string  
      */  
      for j in 2 .. ( length(col_names) - length(replace(col_names,',')) ) + 2 loop  
        rowset(j).tab_varchar2(i) :=   
          regexp_substr(rowset(1).tab_varchar2(i), '[^,]+', 1, j - 1);  
      end loop;  
    end loop;  
      
    /* Output the new columns and their values */  
    dbms_tf.put_row_set(rowset);  
      
  end;  
    
end csv_pkg; 
/

create or replace function csv_to_columns(  
  tab table, col_names varchar2  
) return table pipelined row polymorphic using csv_pkg; 
/

with rws as (
  select data from disp_data
)
select c1, c2, c4, c4, c5, c6, c11
from   csv_to_columns ( 
  rws, 'c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11'
);

C1                   C2                             C4         C4         C5         C6                   C11       
-------------------- ------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------------- ----------
"Project title as pe "The values are not with respe "Disabled" "Disabled" "25 tonnes "www.examplesites.co "25"      
r the outstanding Re ct to the requirement and anal                        of fuel"  m/html.asp&net;"               
quirements"          ysis done by the team.                                                                         
                     Also it is difficult to prepar                                                                 
                     e a scenario notwithstanding t                                                                 
                     he fact it is difficult. This                                                                  
                     user story is going to be slig                                                                 
                     htly complex however it is up                                                                  
                     to the team"
```